# PHP - PHPGraphLib - changing the font-size of the values in the graph?

Tags: phpgraphlib

I am generating graphs from mysql database but the font-size of the values in the graph are very small (like 8px or 9 px).how to make them bigger? is there  any parameter like "$graph->setDataValues(true);" or "$graph->setDataValueColor('navy');"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please go to [ask]

Comment: Thanks but its clear for someone who used the phpgraphlib